# Can you install/activate windows 10 with a MSDN Windows 7 ultimate key?

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, msdn, volume-license

I have read numerous times that you are able to register windows 10 with either a windows 7 or windows 8 license key that has never been activated, *or* with a windows 7/8 VLK.

I currently have several legacy test machines running MSDN copies of windows 7 ultimate. The "free upgrade" window to win10 has come and gone, so I don't believe I can install windows 7 and upgrade to 10 through that path. So, I am looking to wipe one of the machines, and get it running windows 10 directly.

I know MSDN is no more, but the windows 7 license appears to work still. I also know that the MSDN versions of windows aren't an exact bit-for-bit copy of the normal versions (different OS media to install).

Does anyone know if you can use an MSDN VLK from windows 7 to register windows 10?

Just trying to figure out if I need to purchase a copy of windows 10, or if the MSDN keys we have will work.

Comment: The free upgrade offer expired on July 29th 2016.  There currently is an upgrade offer for those that need special programs which expires I believe Dec 29th 2017.  Will Windows 10 activate with your Windows 7 key, it will indeed activate, but unless you applicable to the current offer its ethically dubious to do so.  "I also know that the MSDN versions of windows aren't an exact bit-for-bit copy of the normal versions (different OS media to install)." - **Yes there are**  The only difference is how they are activated which has nothing to do with the ISO being used.

Comment: @Ramhound till end of 2017 MS still allows using win7/8.1 key to upgrade to Win10.

Comment: @magicandre1981 - The current upgrade offer is only valid if you require assistive technology.  You should also read what I said, I never said you cannot use a eligible license key to a previous version of Windows to activate Windows 10, I said to do so, when you are not eligible for the offer is dubious.

Comment: @Ramhound this is the official statement, but everyone is still able to upgrade

Answer (score 2):

If you still have Windows 7 SP1/8.1 installed on the machines, you can try the [Windows 10 upgrade for assistive technology users](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/accessibility/windows10upgrade) until December 31.

You don't have to enable the Accessibilities Features on the system. Download the executable, follow the steps and wait for the system update.

NOTE: First check the specs on the machines. If they are "older" is probably that they will not be able to run Windows 10.